# Using async/await with a for in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, nestjs

I have an Object that name is uploadedFiles. when I run this code first run console.log then run the for so I get the empty array. how can I solve the problem

```
 let orderFilesData = [];
      for (let key in uploadedFiles) {
        uploadedFiles[key].map(async (file) => {
          let id = file.id;
          const orderFile = await this.orderFileRepository.findOne(id);
          orderFile.order = order;    
          await this.orderFileRepository.save(orderFile);
          orderFilesData.push(orderFile.fileUrl);
        });
      }
console.log(orderFilesData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that `Array.map` is async, so even though each one of the calls to save has `await` in front of it, iterating the elements and calling the anonymous function inside the `.map` is done in an async manner.

Try replacing `uploadedFiles[key].map` with a simple `for` loop and I believe that it'll fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Since you do not return any data from the map, try using a `foreach` loop. Since you use an `async` function, what you set in `orderFilesData` will be an array of promises, and you'll have to `await` them. The simplest solution is to use `Promise.all` the array `(console.log(Promise.all(orderFilesData))` should do what you want)

Answer (score 2):

when array.map is used with async function it returns back a list of promises that is not runned. You'll have to start the process with `Promise.all` (or other).

Try this inside your for loop

```js
 const uploadPromises = uploadedFiles[key].map(async (file) => {
       ...
  });
  await Promise.all(uploadPromises)
```

Answer (score 0):

`uploadedFiles` seem to be an object, where the values of the keys are arrays? So if you call `uploadedFiles[key].map(...)` you are creating an array of promises where each of them seems to be awaited. But as the callback of `map` is asynchronous, you are in fact not awaiting. The simplest would be using `Promise.all()` to await all promises in the array of promises resulting from map.

```
  let orderFilesData = [];
  for (let key in uploadedFiles) {
    await Promise.all(uploadedFiles[key].map(async (file) => {
      let id = file.id;
      const orderFile = await this.orderFileRepository.findOne(id);
      orderFile.order = order;    
      await this.orderFileRepository.save(orderFile);
      orderFilesData.push(orderFile.fileUrl);
    }));
  }
 console.log(orderFilesData);
```

But for this to work, make sure the surrounding function is `async`