# How to map over images array and upload them without having the same name for each image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code, where I have an array of images `images` and uploading each image in that array. the code is working fine, but I have an issue, where all the uploaded images have the same name ex: `storage/1671621889.png`.

```
  const uploadData = async (data) => {
    const attachment = []
    const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/file/upload`
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }

    await Promise.all(images.map(async (file, index) => {
        const imageData = new FormData()
        imageData.append('file', file)
        imageData.append('fileName', file?.name)
        let result
        axios.post(url, imageData, config)
        .then(function(response) {
          result = response.data.data.file 
          attachment.push(result)
        })
    }))
    .then(() => {
      submit(data, attachment)
    })
  }
```

I tried awaiting the request, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: try for in loop read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67691514/using-async-await-with-a-for-in-loop#answer-67691770

Comment: Additionally, you should either `await` the `axios.post` inside the map, or return it. Otherwise your `Promise.all` is not doing what you expect it.

Answer (score 4):

You're defining your upload file name already as `file?.name`. If you must make it unique for each request, you can simply append the index.

```js
  const uploadData = async (data) => {
    const attachment = []
    const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/file/upload`
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }

    await Promise.all(images.map(async (file, index) => {
        const imageData = new FormData()
        imageData.append('file', file)
        imageData.append('fileName', `${file?.name}_${index}`)
        let result
        axios.post(url, imageData, config)
        .then(function(response) {
          result = response.data.data.file 
          attachment.push(result)
        })
    }))
    .then(() => {
      submit(data, attachment)
    })
  }
```